# Spit DataTable into two by Rows

Tags: c#, asp.net, datatable, datalist

I have one asp.net datatable and I want to databind into two asp.net datalists, so I though to slice the datatable **rows** in two datatables both the same size if even .

Comment: slice means what vertically or horizontally

Comment: No matters. Just split the datatable data into two new datatables.

Comment: I mean to say all the columns will be their in both the datatables

Comment: @krshekhar Yes the columns will be the same in both datatables. Only the rows must be splitted. Description updated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the [`Take`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb503062.aspx) LINQ extension method to specify how many items to use.

And the [`Skip`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb358985.aspx) to jump over if needed.

```
var half = myList.Take(myList.Count / 2);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are slicing by rows, you can simply create a copy of your original data table, find a suitable half way point, and just import the rows into the copy, while deleting them from the original.

Something like the following should work:

```
DataTable originalTable = new DataTable();
//Load the data into your original table or wherever you get your original table from

DataTable otherTable = originalTable.Copy(); //Copys the table structure only - no data

int rowCount = originalTable.Rows.Count;
int wayPoint = rowCount / 2; //NB integer division rounds down towards 0

for(int i = 0; i <= wayPoint; i++)
{
    otherTable.ImportRow(originalTable.Rows[i]); //Imports (copies) the row from the original table to the new one
    originalTable.Rows[i].Delete(); //Marks row for deletion
}

originalTable.AcceptChanges(); //Removes the rows we marked for deletion
```

Comment: I want to split by number of columns and not rows.